# SonarQube docker keeps stopping

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I am testing out SonarQube locally on my machine using docker, however the docker container keeps stopping, not sure why this is the case. Am using Mac and am not sure if the Java version affects SonarQube but am running Java version 11 on my machine.

These are the logs I am getting

```
2021.07.22 16:49:46 INFO app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp

2021.07.22 16:49:46 INFO app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:39173]

2021.07.22 16:49:46 INFO app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch

2021.07.22 16:49:47 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running

2021.07.22 16:49:47 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1

2021.07.22 16:49:47 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped

2021.07.22 16:49:47 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

This is the command I used to run the docker container

```
docker run --name sonarqube --restart always -p 9000:9000 -d sonarqube
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version of docker on my machine to the latest(Been skipping for almost a year) and it worked